# Write multiple value from API response to csv

Tags: powershell

I am getting response from an API from where I have to pick 4 values and write to csv

I wrote below code which is working when I am doing it for 2 values

```
$Result_IPAddress = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Credential $creds -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'
    
    $IPAddress = $Result_IPAddress.result.ip_address
    $IPStatus = $Result_IPAddress.result.status
    
    [int]$max = $IPAddress.Count
    if ([int]$IPStatus.count -gt [int]$IPAddress.count) { $max = $IPStatus.Count; }
 
        $Results = for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++)
            {
                Write-Verbose "$($IPAddress[$i]),$($IPStatus[$i])"
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IPAddress = $IPAddress[$i]
        IPStatus = $IPStatus[$i] 
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\$($subnet).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Now I have to add 2 more values to it

```
    $IPName =   $Result_IPAddress.result.names
    $IPType =   $Result_IPAddress.result.types
```

The values are coming like below. e.g.
**IPType**

```
NETWORK
A
PTR
HOST
HOST
HOST
HOST
```

**IPName**

```
navde.sg.com
B001DB.net
B9001DB..net
cfro.net
cfrso.net
cfrs9vo.net
```

Currently for 2 values I am getting csv value like

```
"IPAddress","IPStatus"
"10.1.13.0","USED"
"10.1.13.1","UNUSED"
"10.1.13.2","UNUSED"
"10.1.13.3","UNUSED"
"10.1.13.4","UNUSED"
```

Expected output in csv

```
"IPAddress","IPStatus","IPName","IPType"
"10.1.13.0","USED","navde.sg.com","NETWORK"
"10.1.13.1","UNUSED","B001DB.net","A"
"10.1.13.2","UNUSED","B9001DB.net","HOST"
"10.1.13.3","UNUSED","cfro.net","HOST"
"10.1.13.4","UNUSED","cfrso.net","HOST"
```

Please need some help to do this

---

I tried the below code

Output I am getting is like below for both below cases

```
"IPAddress","IPStatus","IPName","IPType"
"10.15.9.0","USED","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
"10.15.9.1","UNUSED","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
"10.15.9.2","UNUSED","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
"10.15.9.3","UNUSED","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
```

because the **$item** value is

```
_ref         : ipv4address/Li5pcHY0X2FkZHJlc3MkMTAuMTU1Ljk5LjIzNC8w:10.155.99.234
ip_address   : 10.15.9.0
is_conflict  : False
mac_address  : 
names        : {}
network      : 10.15.9.0/23
network_view : default
objects      : {}
status       : USED
types        : {}
usage        : {}
```

and some cases the **$item** is coming like below

```
_ref         : ipv4address/Li5pcHY0X2FkZHJlc3MkMTAuMTU1Ljk5LjIzNS8w:10.15.9.23
ip_address   : 10.15.9.23
is_conflict  : False
mac_address  : 
names        : {cfrsv50251003ap.net, cfrsv50251003ap.net}
network      : 10.15.98.0/23
network_view : default
status       : USED
types        : {HOST, A, PTR}
usage        : {DNS}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you need a `for` loop in this case, try using this:

```
$req = @{
    Uri = $url
    Method = 'Get'
    Credential = $creds
    Headers = $headers
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}

$Result_IPAddress = Invoke-RestMethod @req

$Results = foreach($item in $Result_IPAddress.Result)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IPAddress = $item.IP_Address
        IPStatus = $item.Status
        IPName = $item.Names -join ' ;'
        IPType = $item.Types -join ' ;'
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\$($subnet).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

This should also work and is even simpler than a loop, thanks [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) for pointing it out :)

```
$req = @{
    Uri = $url
    Method = 'Get'
    Credential = $creds
    Headers = $headers
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod @req |
Select-Object @{Name='IPAddress';Expression='IP_Address'},
              @{Name='IPStatus';Expression='Status'},
              @{Name='IPName';Expression={$_.Names -join ' ;'}},
              @{Name='IPType';Expression={$_.Types -join ' ;'}} |
Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\$($subnet).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: At which point you don't need a `foreach` loop either: `Invoke-RestMethod ... |Select @{Name='IPAddress';Expression='IP_Address'},@{Name='IPStatus';Expression='Status'},IPName,IPType` :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen indeed haha

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I think it should be `(Invoke-RestMethod @req).Result | Select....` according to OP's code right?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen,@SantiagoSquarzon : I tried the solution given. updated my question with the output.

Comment: @EmptyCoder I updated the code, now it should work, both properties `Names` and `Types` are arrays hence why you see `object[]` when exporting to CSV. Now each element should be joined with `;` as delimiter tho I'm not sure how do you actually want to display that data.